# Changing the zip compression algorithm used by sfdx force:source:push?

Tags: salesforcedx

We have a zipped static resource (our help documentation that includes lots of images) that is of size 4,977,413 bytes when zipped using [Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html#BEST_COMPRESSION). But once converted to SFDX format, a `sfdx force:source:push` reports:

> static resource cannot exceed 5MB

as presumably it is using a different compression algorithm.

Is the SFDX code that does the compression accessible i.e. is it somewhere in the `node_modules`? And if so, where is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is going to be configurable any way sensibly for you. From reading the source, there seems to be a few different ways that `sfdx` deals with archives. From a quick read, the most likely looking culprit for you is in

`sfdx-cli\node_modules\salesforce-alm\dist\lib\staticResource.js`

which has `static zipDir(dir)` which I *think* is responsible for rezipping the exploded static resource. It in turn delegates to

`sfdx-cli\node_modules\salesforce-alm\dist\lib\srcDevUtil.js`

Which ultimately uses https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver to do the actual archiving. As far as I can tell, `sfdx-cli` always passes in `Z_BEST_COMPRESSION` so not much can be done about improving the compression rate.

I don't suppose it is easy to break up the static resource into several different?

Comment: Thank-you for looking! I guess Java's best and the JavaScript code's best are a bit different. This ZIP will move to a documentation server in a few months time and we can work round this meanwhile. But I'll take a second look based on your observations when i have a bit of time.